# jQuery Source File runs together; what do I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

So my supervisor goes to this convention related to our industry, and comes back with all this new and exciting material (she was the one excited).  Part of that was a set of jQuery source files (I have very little experience in jScript, much less jQuery) and expects me to implement it in our environment. Here is a fragment of how I received the code:

```
(function(a,b){function cg(a){return d.isWindow(a)?a:a.nodeType===9?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}function cd(a){if(!bZ[a]){var b=d("<"+a+">").appendTo("body"),c=b.css("display");b.remove();if(c==="none"||c==="")c="block";bZ[a]=c}return bZ[a]}function cc(a,b){var c={};d.each(cb.concat.apply([],cb.slice(0,b)),function(){c[this]=a});return c}function bY(){try{return new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}}function bX(){try{return new a.XMLHttpRequest}catch(b){}}function bW(){d(a).unload(function(){for(var a in bU)bU[a](0,1)})}function bQ(a,c){a.dataFilter&&(c=a.dataFilter(c,a.dataType));var e=a.dataTypes,f={},g,h,i=e.length,j,k=e[0],l,m,n,o,p;for(g=1;g<i;g++){if(g===1)for(h in a.converters)typeof h==="string"&&(f[h.toLowerCase()]=a.converters[h]);l=k,k=e[g];if(k==="*")k=l;else if(l!=="*"&&l!==k){m=l+" "+k,n=f[m]||f["* "+k];if(!n){p=b;for(o in f){j=o.split(" ");if(j[0]===l||j[0]==="*"){p=f[j[1]+" "+k];if(p){o=f[o],o===!0?n=p:p===!0&&(n=o);break}}}
```

Formatting does not exist in this file.  **Are there any tools that will at least format this code out? (newlines, tabs, etc..)**  Granted, I'm pretty sure the example provided could be a jQuery Library source file, but even the custom code that came with is exactly like this.

Comment: If this is the way your boss presents to you new tools for the job, I'd suggest you find another job.

Comment: You can prettify javascript online via http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @swatkins I think that may be exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: And afa the sup, she is not a programmer at all.  I don't hold against her too much.  I just think of it as *Challenge Accepted*.

Comment: @swatkins Make it into an anwser, and a I'll consider it *Answer Accepted*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prettify javascript online via http://jsbeautifier.org

Answer (score 2):

The code you are looking at is the minified source, if you want the non-minified source, you'll have to get it from one of the cdn's or http://jQuery.com itself. ( http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js )

If you wish to begin learning jquery, I would suggest starting with http://www.learningjquery.com/ and following a few demos from the Beginner category.

Edit: Actually... a lot of those demos may be out of date. They will atleast show you the concepts, however in the newest version there may be some syntax differences.